# spectrum of invertible operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator and it is invertible. If we define $M(T)=\displaystyle\sup_{\left\|f\right\|=1}\left\langle f|Tf\right\rangle,m(T)=\displaystyle\inf_{\left\|f\right\|=1}\left\langle f|Tf\right\rangle$ then we can prove that $\sigma(T)\subset [m(T),M(T)].$ Now the question is Define $M(T^{-1}),m(T^{-1})$ and Show that $\sigma(T^{-1})\subset [M(T)^{-1},m(T)^{-1}].$

Comment: I think you mean the operator to be self-adjoint. Also, what difficulty are you having with this exercise? (See: [How to ask a Good Question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959))

Comment: Yes the operator is self adjoint. The difficulty is relation between M(T^{-1}),m(T^{-1}) and M(T)^{-1},m(T)^{-1}.

Comment: you should then edit your question with these additional informations.